# Bilinear Pairing Library: bash syntax error near unexpected token newline' ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, output, newline

I am new to ubuntu. kindly help me with this error. I am executing this

```
gcc -I$/usr/local/include/pbc -I$/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -L$/usr/local/lib -o bls bls.c -lpbc -lgmp
```

the object file is formed without any errors. but when i try to execute this command

```
$ ./bls \<\~/home/src/pbc-0.5.14/param/a.param
```

i am getting this error message

```
bash syntax error near unexpected token newline' ubuntu
```

pls tell me how to fix this?

i am expecting that the code will run and show the output messages.

Comment: Please copy-paste the *actual* commands and the *actual* error message into the question. The build command you show should not work, which makes both your command and output suspect.

Comment: Also please make sure your tags are correct. You have tagged C++, but you build with a C source file. And that isn't really relevant to the problem itself, so the C language tag should probably be removed.